# How to know which version of sinatra is installed on linux?

Tags: linux, sinatra

I'm on the terminal, I don't know how to check the version of sinatra I have installed on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is going to vary widely depending on:

1. Whether you have more than one Ruby installed (e.g. a system Ruby and one installed through RVM, ruby-build, or ruby-install)
2. Which Ruby version you have selected when you look for the Sinatra gem
3. Whether or not you are using Bundler, and used Bundler to install Sinatra

The short, short answer is:

```
gem list --local sinatra
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of Sinatra with `Sinatra::VERSION` once the gem is required.